# Density of invertible differentiable functions.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let's consider $\mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) $ and  a topology $\tau$ (I do believe it exists) such that $\circ: \mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) \times \mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a continuous function.

Is there any $\tau$ such that invertible function are dense?
If there is one, is it in any way generalizable to $\mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$?

Comment: What is meant by $\mathcal{C}'$? Does this mean first differentiable?

Comment: Yes. I do mean it.

Comment: There are certainly good topologies on $\mathcal{C}'(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ such as a Sobolev Norms. As for you condition that invertible functions are dense, there are some topologies such as the indiscreet topology. As for a useful topology, I would guess no, since $f(x)=x^2$ seems quite far from being invertable.

Comment: And so? I said dense.

Comment: You need at least to introduce some restrictions on $\tau$. The trivial topology (only the whole space and the empty set are open) satisfies your conditions "trivially" and I doubt very much that you'll be happy with this answer ;).

Comment: Let's say "the finest" topology that is contained in the topology of puntctual convergense.